# nvd3: control guideline programmatically

Tags: nvd3.js

I'm working on a project where I want to represent different data with the same date range on x-axis using nvd3 (angular).

My idea is to synchronize guideline among different charts and `onmousemove` or using a slider I want to show programmatically guideline with a tooltip in each chart (e.g. [like heroku does](https://dashboard.heroku.com/images/doms.mp4))
[image]

Can anyone give a hint to a solution or if it's possible to control interactive guideline programmatically?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - the default line chart already works like that with multiple series sharing the same guideline? http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html

Comment: I want to synchronize guideline among different charts, which has same date range on x-axis. for instance, I have date range slider, when I drag it I want to show programmatically guideline with a tooltip in each chart

Comment: Did you try using something like `chart1.interactiveLayer.dispatch.onmousemove({ mouseX: mouseXFromEvent, mouseY: mouseYFromEvent);`

Comment: I have the same problem...searched everywhere can't find a solution...Have you solved it yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not